# Why the following C# code throws NullReferenceException on nullable DateTime initialization?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, nullable

Here's some simple code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var coll = new List<string> {"test", "test2", "test3"};

        var filteredColl = coll.Select(x => x).ToList();

        if (!filteredColl.Any())
        {
            DateTime? date = new DateTime();

            filteredColl = coll.Where(x => date.GetValueOrDefault().Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == x).Select(x => x).ToList();
        }
    }
```

The question is, **why the following steps make it crash with NullReferenceException**:

1) Breakpoint to the if

[image: Breakpoint]

2) Set the next execution point:

[image: Execution point]

3) Try to continue with F10:

[image: Exception]

If I comment out the last line of the code, it won't crash.

Update: Here's the stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467261  
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
Source=ConsoleApplication28   StackTrace:
       at ConsoleApplication28.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs: line 21
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:
```

Comment: That's weird. This line shouldn't throw any `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I'm able to compile your full code without an NRE.

Comment: I created a brand new console project, added the code there and it is still crashing when I follow the steps mentioned above. This is with a .NET Framework 4.5 project.

Comment: I updated the post with a stack trace. Maybe an issue with Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Are you trying to debug a release build?

Comment: I'm not doing any strange tricks :) The full code of the app is posted above. It's a brand new console project run with F5 (using the debug configuration as that is the default).

Comment: I get it too, if you just run the code it will not enter the `if(..)`, you have to manually set the next line. Looking at the `new Datetime()` part it has errors on the `MaxValue` and `MinValue` - *Cannot dereference expression. The pointer is not valid*. If you remove the `not` from the `if(..)` it runs fine, as does putting the line outside the `if(..)` block....

Comment: I can reproduce it with Visual Studio 2010 in debug mode. Does not happen if the `DateTime?` is declared outside the `if`-statement or if the last line in the `if` will be removed which uses this variable.

Comment: Btw, the same with `default(DateTime)` or `DateTime.Now` but not with other nullables like `int?`.

Comment: If you watch the right hand side, you'll see the Min/MaxValue fields have errors in them until the `if(..)` is found to be true and the code enters the block

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a side-effect of moving the execution point inside a context that declares a captured variable scope. It would be reasonable to report it as an IDE bug, but it would not be trivial to fix. Basically, `date` is not a *variable* - it is a *field* on a capture-context, because of the lambda. The compiler essentially does:

```
if (!filteredColl.Any())
{
    var ctx = new SomeCaptureContext(); // <== invented by the compiler
    ctx.date = new DateTime();

    filteredColl = coll.Where(ctx.SomePredicate).Select(x => x).ToList();
}
```

where `SomePredicate` is:

```
class SomeCaptureContext {
    public DateTime? date; // yes, a public field - needs to support 'ref' etc
    public bool SomePredicate(string x) // the actual name is horrible
    {
        return this.date.GetValueOrDefault()
              .Date.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) == x;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when you drag the execution position to:

```
DateTime? date = new DateTime();
```

You are *actually* (in IL terms) dragging it to the line:

```
ctx.date = new DateTime();
```

The capture-context line immediately before that, i.e.

```
var ctx = new SomeCaptureContext();
```

never got executed, so `ctx` is `null`. Hence the `NullReferenceException`.

It would be reasonable to log this as a bug, but it is a subtle one - and you wouldn't necessarily *always* want dragging the execution context to initialize the capture-contexts - it would have to be "if they are `null`".

Comment: Your explanation is great, but if you drag the execution point to the opening parenthesis under `if (!filteredColl.Any())`, you still get the same Exception. Shouldn't the scope be declared after that parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Really it looks weird. 
Do you have mscorlib in references and System in usings? 
Maybe you have some another class named DateTime and it overrides System.DateTime.